# Get size of CentOS folder for a user via SSH

Tags: ssh, centos5

I've been working on a back up script for a client, however if I get the size via FTP account, it takes a long time to load the page, was wondering if running a SSH command via PHP would be much quicker? Could anyone tell me what commands would I need to use to determine a folder size in kb?

OR

To get a user quota used? as I have a FTP user for each backup account, so just need to know how much it's using

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the size in kb for each home-dir in /home:

```
for username in `ls /home/`
do
    echo "Size for is $username `du -hs /home/$username/ --block-size=1024 | cut -f1`kb"
done
```

If you have a list somewhere of the ftp-users, you could modify this script to use that list by putting that into the for-loop.

```
for username in `awk -F: '{print $1}' /home/mylistwithusers`
```

Comment: Could you tell me how I would get a file size in KB for a folder in /home/backuos/user1/ ? As can't figure out how to format this.. Thanks!

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius That would be: `du -s /home/backuos/user1/* --block-size=1024` or `du -s /home/backuos/* --block-size=1024`. Your question is a bit ambiguous. Hope that helps!

Comment: oen last question, your commands print out every directories size in the folder, how can I just get back the size for the whole thing? I tried using -c but it still includes all of the other folders.. it works if I navigate to the directory and run du -s but then I need to navigate to it and I don't wan't to do that every time.. Would appreciate the help!

Comment: Achieved it with du -sh /home/backups/13/* --block-size=1024  | awk '{total=total+$1} END {print total}'

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just use the [filesize() function in PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php#94566) recursively to get the entire directory size?

Comment: I already said this takes to long to load because of that!

Comment: "however if I get the size via FTP account" makes it sound like you logged into an FTP server to get the size... if the directory is on the server itself, it could be quick.